# Is it possible to create a backup image of an already installed sql server? (complete image not just configuration file installation)

Tags: sql-server, installation

I am wondering if it is possible to create an image of an already installed SQL server on my machine?

The issue is as follows:

I have SQL server developer 2014 and 2016 with all components installed on my machine (Sql server, SSIS, SSRS, SSAS), my OS is Windows 10 pro (upgraded from windows 8.1), and recently I had windows 10 anniversary update and I am having a lot of issues since this then, so I want to reset Windows (resetting resolved same issues I had with my other computers).

I know I can use configuration file installation, but this will not include all the components and will not have setting for things like Management Data Warehouse and SSAS query history.

So I am asking if there is a way to generate an image of the already installed SQL server and it's components and just re-install that image again after resetting windows?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built in SQL Server tool to do this (Oracle does have such a tool) and many dbas think because they can restore a database they have done enough in the area of backup. You can use VMWARE (Virtual Machine Converter) to create an image of your machine or you have to backup all the databases (including the system dbs) that are installed on your machine, all the binaries (programs both SQL Server and non-SQL Server utils such as antivirus) and all the settings at the system level (especially accounts).

The best way to check is to do a bare metal restore and see if the machine matches what you have exactly.